# C++ classes query error : left of "" must point to class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class, pointers, setter

I'm trying to implement a class called Person that consists of the members : name , gender and ads where ads is of a class type called Address that consists of the members street , tel and PObox. When i compile the program i get an error for whenever i try to call ads inside any of the Person implementations (although the syntax should be correct) . I have attached the address.h , person.h ,implementation for Person and implementation for Address files .

**address.h**

```
#include<iostream>
class Address
{
public:
    Address();
    char* getstreet();
    char* gettel();
    int getpobox();
    void setall(char *str , char *tel , int pobox);
    void print();
    /*~Address();*/

private:
    char* street;
    char* tel;
    int POBox; 
};
```

**person.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "address.h" // header file for the Address class
#include "gender.h" // header file for the Gender enum 
using namespace std;
class Person
{
  public:
    Person();
    Person(char *n, Gender *g, Address *ad);
    Person(const Person &f);
    void setName(char * n);
    void setAds( Address *ad); 
    char *getName();
    /*Address *getAds();*/
    /*~Person();*/
    void print();

private:
    char *name;
    Gender *gender; 
    Address *ads;
};
```

**Implementation 2.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#ifndef address_h
#define address_h
#include"address.h"
using namespace std;
//IMPLEMENTATION OF ADDRESS FUNCTIONS

Address::Address()
    {
        street = "default street";
        tel = "55555555";
        POBox = 1315425;
    }
    char* Address::getstreet()
    {
        return street;
    }
    char* Address::gettel()
    {
        return tel;
    }
    int Address::getpobox()
    {
        return POBox;
    }
    void Address::setall(char *str , char *tel2 , int pobox)
    {
    street = str;
    tel = tel2;
    POBox = pobox;
    }
    void Address::print()
    {
        cout<<"Street : "<<street<<endl;
        cout<<"Telephone : "<<tel<<endl;
        cout<<"PO box : "<<POBox<<endl;
    }

#endif
```

**Implementation.cpp**

```
#ifndef person_h
#define person_h
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include"address.h"
#include"person.h"
using namespace std;
    //IMPLEMENTATION OF PERSON FUNCTIONS
    Person::Person()
    {
        (*gender) = female;
        name = "testname";
        (*ads).setall("random adress","0503216532",95421);
    }
    Person::Person(char *n, Gender *g, Address *ad) //copy constructor
    {
        n = name;
        g = gender;
        ad->setall("cpyconstruct test","42324134",14925);
    }
    Person::Person(const Person &f)
    {
        name = f.name;
        gender = f.gender;
        ads = f.ads;
    }
    void Person:: setName(char * n)
    {
        n = "karim (TESTING SETNAME)";
    }
    void Person::setAds(Address *ad)
    {
        ads->setall("aus","04314013",14314);
    }
    char* Person::getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void Person:: print()
    {
        cout<<"Name : "<<name<<endl;
        if(gender == 0)
        {
        cout<<"gender : male"<<endl;
        }
        else
        cout<<"gender : female"<<endl;
        ads->setall("hello","056323453",1995);
    }

#endif
```

Comment: What line does the error say this is on?

Comment: All of the lines where i try to do anything with ads

Comment: You *really* need to be using `std::string`! Otherwise you should be using `char []` or allocating with `new` (but use `std::string`!)

Comment: Where should i allocate with new and why ? @crashmstr

Comment: @KareemYoussef You are assigning string literals to `char *`, which is not a good idea. Instead you should use `std::string` and let the standard library do the heavy lifting. Otherwise, you should be using or allocating with `new` and array of characters and using `strcpy` et. al. for C strings.

Answer (score 0):

ads is an uninitialized pointer, so you can't do anything with it (say, by using the -> operator).

Solution:  initialize with new in Person's ctor; or, better yet, don't use a pointer at all.  You don't need one.

```
class Person
{ 
  ...
  Address ads;
};

Person::Person()
{
    (*gender) = female;
    name = "testname";
    ads.setall("random adress","0503216532",95421);
}
```

...and crashmaster's right:  when you get `ads` working, you're going to get memory problems with Address's members.  Use std::string and they'll be taken care of, too.